# Angular JS - UI router page reload won't set the state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is my main app (app.js)

```
(function(ng, module) {
    module.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("app");

        $stateProvider.state('login', {
            url: 'login',
            templateUrl: '/assets/templates/pages/login.html'
        }).state('root', {
            url: '',
            templateUrl: '/assets/templates/pages/index.html'
        });


    }]);
}) (angular, angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router', 'myapp.submodule']));
```

This is the submodule (submodule.js)

```
(function(ng, module) {
    module.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider){
        $stateProvider.state('root.substate', {
            url: 'todo/{type}',
            templateUrl: '/assets/app/todo/todo.html',
            controller: function($stateParams, $scope) {
                // Do stuff.
            }
        });
    }]);

}) (angular, angular.module('myapp.submodule', ['ui.router']));
```

The expected behaviour would be

- redirect to "app" url when no matching route is found
- activate the "root" state on root url
- activate the "root.substate" state on /todo url

This is working fine.

However, if i do refresh the page, the state is not activated and i'm sent back to "app". Why?

Comment: Maybe not the real issue, but I would **for sure** start any url with `/` -  `url: '/todo/{type}'`

Comment: I'm still testing, but it seems that the leading slash may be the problem.

Comment: Do you know why? Simply, there must be some way how to clearly define where the state url starts. Your mapping of url says: `domain/applogin` in fact... and I suggest: `domain/app/login`. so no slash ... big issues for the engine, if you know what I mean

Comment: Uhm i'm still confused. The leading slash on login and root states fixes them. The nested root.substate state works fine *without* the leading slash, and it's buggy with the leading slash. Buggy = refresh leads to unresolved route. Edit: Buggy = url it's rendered as foo.bar/#//todo (double slash). I think i'm missing something about url generation

Comment: Will try to show you how to in answer.. give me sec

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have two *root* states *(no parent)* states. These should be either having **no** url, or it should start with some unique sign - the best choice would always with (URI spec) be a **`/`**:

```
// domain/app/login - easy to find
.state('login', {
    url: 'login',
    ...
})
// no def === domain/app
.state('root', {
    url: '',
    ...
});
```

Now, let's use some `url` even for our `'root'` state  :

```
// domain/app/
.state('root', {
    url: '/',
    ...
});
```

That mans, that our child 'root.substate' will also contain the parent `url` part. So if we would use this

```
// this is a child and its url will be in fact: domain/app//todo/sometype
.state('root.substate', {
    url: '/todo/{type}',
    ...
});
```

See, that this way, our url will now for child contain // (double slash)

To avoid that, we can use UI-Router feature '^'

```
// this stat will not use the parent part
// this will work domain/app/todo/sometype
.state('root.substate', {
    url: '^/todo/{type}',
    ...
});
```

Check the doc:

[Absolute Routes (^)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#absolute-routes-)

> If you want to have absolute url matching, then you need to prefix your url string with a special symbol '^'.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('contacts', {
     url: '/contacts',
     ...
  })
  .state('contacts.list', {
     url: '^/list',
     ...
  });
```

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow. Enjoy mighty UI-Router ;)

Comment: I tried this solution and it works. But i still have issues with refreshing the page leading to the default route ($otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

I know a lot of time left. But about issue with refreshing. If you want to stay on the same url address as before refreshing you should add next:

```
angular.module('app').run(['$state', '$stateParams', function($state, $stateParams) {
   //this solves page refresh and getting back to state
}]);
```

like mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/105) in pre-last answer