# Routing wierdness in angular with ui-routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Another question guys :)
If I leave the templateUrl empty in my routing, the scope is queriable but no template showing. But if I write it just as in the linked plunker project, it makes the links unclickable :( but just for the li > a elements... also in plunker I cannot make it workable, don't know why... anyone?
http://plnkr.co/edit/VKhhcSmepMTxBT7R5AuO

And here is the ap.js itself for helping

```
(function(){
    var portApp = angular.module('portApp', ['ui.router']);

    portApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
        $stateProvider
            .state('root', {
                url: '/home',
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: 'views/listView.html',
                controller: 'ListController'
            })
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: 'views/listView.html',
                controller: 'ListController'
            })
            .state('about', {
                url: '/about',
                templateUrl: 'views/resumeView.html'
            })
            .state('items', {
                url: '/items/:itemLink',
                templateUrl: 'views/itemView.html',    
                controller: 'ItemController'
            });
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });

    portApp.factory("workFactory", function() {
        var works = [
        {
            Title: "Sprite",
            subTitle: "",
            Link: "sprite",
            Thumbnail: "img/portfolio02.png",
            Image: "img/ismont.png"
        },
        {
            Title: "Pepsi",
            subTitle: "Kristályvíz",
            Link: "pepsi",
            Thumbnail: "img/portfolio03.png",
            Image: "img/sanofimont.png"
        }
        ];
        return {
            list: function() {
                return works;
            },
            selected: function(detPath) {
                selected = works.filter(function(work) {
                    return work.Link == detPath;
                });
                return selected;
            }
        };
    });

    portApp.controller("ListController", ["$scope", "workFactory", 
        function($scope, workFactory) {
            $scope.allWorks = workFactory.list();
        }
    ]);

    portApp.controller("ItemController", ["$scope", "workFactory", "$stateParams",
        function($scope, workFactory, $stateParams) {
            var detPath = $stateParams.itemLink;
            //$scope.selectedWork = workFactory.selected(detPath);
            $scope.selectedWork = workFactory.selected(detPath)[0];
            alert($scope.selectedWork);
        }
    ]);

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [an updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XULlsPDslmLEMWfPJtp1?p=preview)

I am not fully sure what you want to do with your root state, so I used it the way I do...

```
$stateProvider
    .state('root', {
        abstract: true,
        template: '<div ui-view=""></div>',
        resolve: {
          somedata: function(){return {}}
        }
    })
    .state('home', {
        parent: 'root',
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'listView.html',
        controller: 'ListController'
    })
    .state('about', {
      parent: 'root',
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'resumeView.html'
    })
    .state('items', {
       parent: 'root',
        url: '/items/:itemLink',
        templateUrl: 'itemView.html',    
        controller: 'ItemController'
    });
```

As we can see, super parent state **`'root'`** is not having url defined, and it does contain template *(where all children be injected)*

On the other hand, every state now declares its parent as a 'root'. It will mean, that all states do have access to resolves or any other common stuff later applied to root.

Easy way how to effect all states.. Hope this could help. Maybe check this for some more details: [Angular JS - UI router page reload won't set the state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28366927/1679310)

Comment: Yea, well I used that 'root' only because other ways the ui-sref-active was false to the first menu element at page load for the first time :( But I don't know if there are any other way it could be made to work.

Comment: Still not sure what you really need, but there is an updated plunker without root at all http://plnkr.co/edit/ewJsjeHTmGIPFZqTfZc5?p=preview. Hope this helps

Comment: With a basic ui-routiong settings I can make it to work, BUT my problem is that now it doesn't route me to my itemView :( I think it is due to the root state, which I wrote in because I want my home state to be the default just right after the first pageload, and make it the active menu item.

Comment: My plunkers are working, what is not working for you? Sorry, not sure how to help. If you can formulate question or problem differently, I am ready to assist...

Comment: Ah! I figured it out... I was missing the base-href tag in my index.html file... which I as far as I know is only needed when I use ngroute. But since I use the ui-route, it's not important to use. Why do we need still use it? This is unclear right now.

Comment: To be honest, I forget to inform you, that I did that change... It was must so I did it ;) And forget... But we do NOT HAVE to do that Just use this `$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});` Check more here  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: It's interesting.. but I accpet that we MUST use it in angular code :) Anyway if i try to use the second version (written in the js itself) it doesn't work for me so I leave inside in the html. Thanks :)

Comment: Great that you made it! Enjoy mighty UI-Router sir ;)